# How do check for duplicate before AddRange?

Tags: entity-framework-core

This is my sample model,

- Name
- Age

I have a list of records for which I will use Entity Framework Core `AddRange`. This is my sample data, say list 1

```
John, 21
Mike, 18
Rick, 19
Alex, 20
```

I have another query which is a list of the existing records, say list 2.

```
John, 21
Alex, 20
```

I want to compare these 2 lists to get what exists in list 1 but not in list 2.

```
Mike, 18
Rick, 19
```

I tried using LINQ `except` but it can't be used for complex types. I also tried to use `.Any` like below but it returns nothing.

```
var result = list1.Where(x=> !list2.Any(y=>x.Name == y.Name));
```

I do not want to check and insert one record at one time. I want to insert by list of objects using `AddRange`.

Is there any Nuget package that can easily get this?

Comment: It is ETL task, like insert of thousand records. Or you need to just check 10-20 records?

Comment: less than 100 records

Comment: *but it returns nothing* -- The code looks like it should. Maybe you abstracted too much for the question? As for complex types, you can use Except with an `IEqualityComparer`.

Answer (score 0):

For not so big amount of records, you can use the following extension:

```cs
var nonExistent = await ctx.Some.GetNonExistentAsync(list2, x => x.Name);
```

Or with complex key:

```cs
var nonExistent = await ctx.Some.GetNonExistentAsync(list2, 
   x => new { x.Name, x.Other });
```

It will generate effective SQL to check which records do not exist.

And implementation:

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static async Task<List<T>> GetNonExistentAsync<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<T> records,
        Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var recordsList = records.ToList();

        var keySelectorCompiled = keySelector.Compile();

        var predicate = BuildPredicate(recordsList, keySelector, keySelectorCompiled);

        var existent = (await query
            .Where(predicate)
            .Select(keySelector)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken))
            .ToHashSet();


        var result = recordsList.Where(r => !existent.Contains(keySelectorCompiled(r))).ToList();
        return result;
    }

    private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildPredicate<T, TKey>(IEnumerable<T> records, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector, Func<T, TKey> keySelectorCompiled)
    {
        var members = CollectMembers(keySelector.Body).ToList();
        if (members.Count == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No key found");

        Expression? predicate = null;

        if (members.Count == 1 && keySelector.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            // we can use Contains

            var recordsSequence = Expression.Constant(records.Select(keySelectorCompiled));

            predicate = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Contains), new[] { typeof(TKey) },
                recordsSequence, keySelector.Body);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                Expression? subPredicate = null;

                var recordExpression = Expression.Constant(record);

                foreach (var m in members)
                {
                    var memberExpression =
                        ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(keySelector.Parameters[0], recordExpression, m);

                    var equality = Expression.Equal(m, memberExpression);
                    subPredicate = subPredicate == null ? equality : Expression.AndAlso(subPredicate, equality);
                }

                if (subPredicate == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(); // should never happen

                predicate = predicate == null ? subPredicate : Expression.OrElse(predicate, subPredicate);
            }
        }

        predicate ??= Expression.Constant(false);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(predicate, keySelector.Parameters);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Expression> CollectMembers(Expression expr)
    {
        switch (expr.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.New:
            {
                var ne = (NewExpression)expr;

                foreach (var a in ne.Arguments)
                foreach (var m in CollectMembers(a))
                {
                    yield return m;
                }

                break;
            }

            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                yield return expr;
                break;

            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The way it's presented in the question, `list1` and `list2` are just in-memory lists.